# Driving strings of high power LEDs - different ways with fault protection

Tags: led-strip, led-driver, lm317

I'm trying to find the best method for driving around 30 x white LEDs plus 10 x RGB. The power supply can be 24V. The LEDs will be dimmable, 3W or 1W, 0.350A or 0.7A (I'd need to limit the current a little below the maximum.) Everything connected to the PWM driver.

I have been making buck converters, but this time I prefer something simpler and small to fit inside the lamp (<12mm height.)

I considered:

- NSI-50350
- LM317. If I calculated it properly it would waste less than 2W.
- Better method? Simple and cheap. If it is not worth putting it inside the case I will consider an external box.

There is one more thing, I've seen somebody using a regulator - maybe an LM317. But he used two little 0805 resistors and he had an LED open and LED short fault detection. It would auto off the whole string or only a small current would flow. I can't find it anymore.

How can I implement it?

Comment: Bad idea to use 24V to an LM317 considering Pd * Rjc and Rca inside a thermally insulated lamp

Comment: Lamp is made of aluminium composite. Quite big surface. Still a bad idea?

Comment: I hope you are aware that switching regulators can be quite compact?  Check out Luxeon Buckpuck and Boostpuck and their knockoffs.  They've been around for 10 years or more, so there are many other similar units in the market.  For single LEDs, you can even give them individual current control by using a switching regulator to feed slightly too much voltage to a common AMC7135 chip, which will give you output and short protection in increments of 350mA current control as they can be paralleled.  You only need 120mV overhead voltage.  The 7135 is fast enough to PWM at LED speeds.

Comment: Regarding what you're asking about Tony's comment, even if the lamp can shed enough heat and it doesn't cause a fire, heat directly correlates with lack of efficiency, so you should also be thinking "What is the point of making an LED lamp if it is only as efficient or less efficient than what it replaces?" and the only acceptable answer I can think of is "Because it is vastly more beautiful.".  Unless you're making art that relies on lack of efficiency for it's aesthetic, you should think about how to make the aesthetics accommodate efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

If you can readily get the NSI50350, I'd tend to go in that direction - or use one of the [related devices.](https://www.onsemi.com/products/power-management/led-drivers/linear-led-drivers)

The NSI50350 is a 350 milliampere constant current regulator.  If your LEDs are rated for 350mA and 3V and and you are using a 24V power supply, just stack 7 LEDs in series.  That'll get you 350 mA to the LEDs very easily.  7 LEDs gives you a little "wiggle room" on the voltage.

[image]

PWM is also easy.  Just use a low side transistor (BJT or MOSFET ,which ever you prefer) and drive it with PWM.  The [NSI50250 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nsi50350ad-d.pdf) shows how:

[image]

ON has a bunch of related chips (linked to above) that all work the same way. Put one in series between the LEDs and voltage source, done.  PWM with a transistor in series.

If you keep the voltage source close to the total voltage of the LEDs (plus headroom,) then the chip won't get very hot - but make sure you do have adequate heat sinking for the chip and the series transistor for the PWM.